# How to set Path for postgresql windows 7?

Tags: postgresql

I am using windows 7 and I dont know how to create a path in the environment variable for psql. In windows 10 its a bit different since you can simply double click on the path and add a new column, but in windows 7 you cant do that (as far as I know). How do i get it done?

Comment: Check this out : http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/562169/how-to-set-path-environment-variable) question covers that.